# How to avoid circular login using passport authentication

Tags: node.js, passport.js, saml-2.0

I am setting up single-sign-on with passport over SAML2 with a nodejs/express backend.  I end up in a loop of some sort..

The process goes like this:

When I go to my app, it calls the `whoami` route, defined below.  On first pass, this should (and does) return a 401 (unauthorized).
When that returns with a 401 (unauthorized) to my app, we then redirect the app to `login`.
The `login` route, defined below, remembers our original URL (so we can go back to it) via `RelayState` and runs `passport.authenticate(....)` before redirecting back to the app. I admit to not knowing how or why we are redirecting back to the application here - and removing it doesn't solve the issue, however, it does, in fact, go out to the SSO provider (defined in the `config.saml.options` object).
The SSO provider does it's magic and returns back to the `/login/callback` route, defined below.  This request has all the needed info in it.
... however... then my app restarts the process... creating a loop of:
WhoAmI -> Login -> LoginCallback -> WhoAmI -> Login -> LoginCallback

It's my understanding that at some point, the backend should be saving the user locally and the subsequent `whoami` call would return the info desired.

How can I stop this circular processing.

My passport.js file:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import passport from 'passport';
import { Strategy } from 'passport-saml';
import config from './config.js';

const savedUsers = [];
passport.serializeUser((expressUser, done) => {
    done(null, expressUser)
});
passport.deserializeUser((expressUser, done) => {
    done(null, expressUser)
});

passport.use(
    new Strategy(
        {
            issuer: config.saml.issuer,
            protocol: 'https://',
            path: '/auth/login/callback',
            entryPoint: config.saml.entryPoint,
            cert: fs.readFileSync(config.saml.cert, 'utf-8'),
            authnContext: ["urn:federation:authentication:windows"],
            identifierFormat: null,  //if omitted the identifier format defaults to urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress
        },
        (expressUser, done) => {
            if (savedUsers.includes(expressUser)) {
                savedUsers.push(expressUser)
            }
            return done(null, expressUser)
        }
    )
)
```

My route definitions for my SAML authentication are:

```
import express from 'express';
import config from '../config/config.js';

import '../config/passport.js'
import session from 'express-session'
import passport from 'passport'

const samlRouter = express.Router();

samlRouter.use(session(config.session));
samlRouter.use(passport.initialize());
samlRouter.use(passport.session());

samlRouter.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log("Use");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.header('origin'));
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-Width, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true'); //SAML

    if (req.method == 'OPTIONS') {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, GET');
        return res.status(200).json({})
    }
    next();
})

samlRouter.get('/whoami', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('whoami');
    if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return res.status(401).json({
            message: 'Unauthorized',
        });
    }
    return res.status(200).json({ user: req.user });
});


samlRouter.get('/login',

    (req, res, next) => {
        console.log('login');
        req.query.RelayState = req.query.origURL;
        passport.authenticate('saml', config.saml.options)(req, res, next)
    },
    (req, res, next) => {
        return res.redirect(`${config.app.location}:3000`);
    }
); 


samlRouter.post('/login/callback',
(req, res, next) => {
        console.log('login/callback');
        passport.authenticate('saml', config.saml.options)(req, res, next)
    },
    (req, res, next) => {
        if(req.user) {
            console.log('req.user.nameID :>> ', req.user?.nameID);   **// THIS OUTPUTS THE CORRECT INFO**
        } else {
            console.log('req.user was falsey');
        }
        
        console.log(`redirect to Relay state ${req.body.RelayState}`);
        return res.redirect(`${req.body.RelayState}`);
    });


export default samlRouter;
```

My application code for getting the user is this:

```
export function getUser() {  
    console.log('Getting user...');
    const RedirectToLogin = () => {
        console.log("Redirecting to xxxx/login...")
        window.location.assign(`https://xxxx/login?origURL=${encodeURIComponent(window.location.href)}`)
    }

    return axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://xxxx/whoami',
        withCredentials: true
    })
        .then(resp => {    // WE NEVER GET HERE...
            if (resp.data.user) {
                console.log(`User Authenticated as ${resp.data.user.nameID}`);
                return Promise.resolve(resp.data.user.nameID)
            }
            else {
                console.warn("Unauthenticated - redirecting to login")
                RedirectToLogin()
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('err :>> ', err);
            console.warn("Unauthenticated -- redirecting to login")
            RedirectToLogin()
        })
}
```

Comment: I am interested to see how you resolved this!

Comment: I'm not sure I did it right, but effectively on the apps whoami call, I include a browser fingerprint.  The backend looks in a table for that fingerprint. If it finds it, it just returns the right info.  If it doesn't, it continues on with the SSO process.
... so the second time through, the app sends the fingerprint and the backend knows who that person is... without needing to continue the SSO loop.